# Need a modern SATA controller for 12 drives (end of 2016)

Tags: sata, raid-controller, sas

I am looking for a SATA controller capable of handling at least 12 drives for a custom personal cloud build. There are a couple good (and cheap) ones that look good on newegg, but the reviews indicate that the drivers are no longer appropriate for newer OS's (target OS in this case will be Ubuntu Server, most recent (16.04)).

I am fine using 4x SAS or 12x+ SATA connections. Also, would be excellent if it was on the smaller side as case space is a premium.

RAID support is optional, as I plan to use software RAID for better error detection and cross-controller support.

I'd like to think ~$500 max, but we will see how available these are.

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: I'd like to think ~$500 max, but we will see how available these are.

Comment: Have you checked the Ubuntu pages for currently compatible controllers?  That is usually the best place to start, and to be honest the place I would be going in order to find things to recommend lol.